# Bounds involving number of invariant factors and elementary divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

> Let $M$ be a finitely generated torsion module over the PID $R$. Suppose that $M$ has $s$ elementary divisors and $t$ invariant factors. Define $$S:=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\,|\,M\text{ is isomorphic to a direct sum of $n$ cyclic modules}\}.$$ (a) Show that $s=\max(S)$.
>
> (b) Show that $t=\min(S)$.

I know that I am supposed to use the classification theorem of finitely generated modules over PID. Thus,

$M \cong \frac{R}{({p_1}^{e_1})}\bigoplus \frac{R}{({p_2}^{e_2})} \bigoplus \ldots \bigoplus \frac{R}{({p_s}^{e_s})}$ where $p_i$'s are primes (not necessarily distinct) and $e_i\geq 1$

The invariant form gives $M \cong \frac{R}{(a_1)}\bigoplus \frac{R}{(a_2)} \bigoplus \ldots \bigoplus \frac{R}{(a_t)}$ where $a_i$'s are non-zero, non-units and $a_i|a_{i+1}$. We know from this that $ann_{R}M=(a_t)$

Naturally both $t,s \in S$. Also, any cyclic R-module is of the form $R/I$ for some ideal $I$. Thus, for some $k \in S$, we have $M \cong R/I_1 \bigoplus R/I_2 \bigoplus+\ldots  \bigoplus R/I_k$ for some ideals $I_1=(b_1),I_2=(b_2), \ldots I_k=(b_k)$ of $R$. Since $ann_R R/I=I$, this gives $ann_RM=\cap I_j$

Thus, $(a_t)=\cap I_j$. Hence, $a_t|b_i$ for $1\leq i \leq k$

I am not sure how to show that $t \leq k$ from this. Also, any hints for part $(a)$?

Thanks!

Comment: Since I liked the question, I give you a few hints (as you requested). In fact, the question is pretty easy. Consider a decomposition of M having n cyclic modules of the form R/(a_i). Write each a_i as a product of prime powers and get $n\le s$. (What represent these prime powers?) Then recover the invariant factors and notice that the way you build them implies that $t\le n$.

Comment: @user26857 So, suppose $M \cong R/b_1 \bigoplus R/b_2 \bigoplus+\ldots  \bigoplus R/b_n$. Write $b_i=p_{i,1}^{e_{i,1}}.p_{i,2}^{e_{i,2}}.\ldots p_{i,s_i}^{e_{i,s_i}}$, i.e. as a product of $s_i$ non-associate primes. Then $R/(b_i) \cong \frac{R}{(p_{i,1}^{e_{i,1}})}\bigoplus \frac{R}{(p_{i,2}^{e_{i,2}})} \bigoplus \ldots \bigoplus \frac{R}{(p_{i,s_i}^{e_{i,s_i}})}$. As number of elementary divisor is $s$, we must have $\sum s_i=s$. But $s_i \geq 1$ $\implies s \geq n.$ Is this correct?

Comment: I think so. ${}$

Comment: @user26857 Thank you! Can you please suggest how to tackle the other direction? How do you get $t \leq n$?

Comment: I already did this! Write the powers of primes in a matrix and recover the invariant factors as you know, by picking one at a time from each column (or row, it depends on how you wrote them). After how many steps the matrix is empty? For instance, if $a_1=2$ and $a_2=3$ the matrix looks like $\left(\begin{array}{cc}2& \\ &3\end{array}\right)$. You pick 2 from the first column and 3 from the second, and get one invariant factor. Btw, the number of invariant factors seems to be $n$, unless the $a_i$' are coprime pairwisely.

Comment: Correction: unless two or more $a_i$'s are coprime pairwisely.